# How do you call a function to run specific code?

Tags: javascript

I'm making my website mobile-friendly and I'm loading different CSS files based on if the user is using a touch device or not. I have edited the question to instead create an alert box to simplify the question.

**Please note:** `LoadCSS(style.css)` has been changed to `alert()`

I want to run javascript code stored in a variable.

From my research, eval(variable) runs/executes the variable as code, but this isn't working.

The code I want to run is stored in "isTouchscreen" and "notTouchscreen".

-- isTouchscreen.js --

```
function ifTouchscreen(isTouchscreen, notTouchscreen) {
// isTouchscreen being alert('Touchscreen device!')
// notTouchscreen being alert('Not a touchscreen device!')

  if(userIsUsingATouchScreen) { 
    eval(isTouchScreen)
} else {
  eval(notTouchScreen);
// expecting "eval" to execute the variables as javascript commands/functions
}
}
```

-- index.html -- [Edited to use "alert"]

```
<!--alert() being commands that I want to be executed-->
ifTouchscreen("alert('Touchscreen device!')", "alert('Not a touchscreen device!')")
```

What I expect to happen is for the "isTouchscreen" variable to be run as javascript code if the user is using a touchscreen device, and for the "notTouchscreen" variable to be run as javascript code if the user is not using a touchscreen device.

I expect an "alert" to take place which doesn't happen.

How do you call a function in javascript with a variable/condition [function(variable/condition)] and get the function to execute said variable/condition as javascript code?

Comment: What's inside `isTouchScreen` and `notTouchScreen`? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: The code for each variable respectively is `LoadCSS('mobile-friendly.css')` and `LoadCSS('normal.css')` as seen in "index.html". I believe I created a function correctly, I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I was more interested in the body of `LoadCSS`, sorry if I wasn't clear, but I guess the actual problem is what's in the answers below.

Comment: You shouldn't have to load different CSS for different devices. Media queries and responsive design principles solves the problem you are having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current code, `LoadCSS(...)` is getting called twice, and the values returned from those calls (probably `undefined`) are being passed as arguments to your function.

It's possible that something like this would work instead:

```
   ifTouchscreen("LoadCSS('mobile-friendly.css')", "LoadCSS('normal.css')")
```

But what you really want to do is pass in a `function` as a "callback" for your code to call into.

```
ifTouchscreen(() => LoadCSS('mobile-friendly.css'), () => LoadCSS('normal.css'))
```

```
function ifTouchscreen(isTouchscreen, notTouchscreen) {

  if(userIsUsingATouchScreen) { 
    isTouchScreen();
  } else {
    notTouchScreen();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load css dynamically like this:

```
function loadCssDynamically(href){
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = href;
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}

function ifTouchscreen(isTouchscreenHref, notTouchscreenHref) {
  if(userIsUsingATouchScreen) { 
    loadCssDynamically(isTouchscreenHref)
  } else {
    loadCssDynamically(notTouchscreenHref);
  }
}

ifTouchscreen('http://website.com/css/stylesheet1.css', 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet2.css')
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that both functions get executed before the call to `ifTouchScreen`.

You must add quotes around it:

```
ifTouchscreen("LoadCSS('mobile-friendly.css')", "LoadCSS('normal.css')")
```

It is also possible I misunderstand and `LoadCSS` is actually returning javascript code as a text.